# User location is undefined

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am getting all other user info but `location` will always be `undefined`.
My FB location is enabled, the pop up ask for this permission ( `hometown`, `current city`) , so I get the hometown/name/etc but no location.

```
 FB.login(function(response) {
                if (response.status === 'connected')
                {
                  console.log("connected");
                  console.log('Access Token: ' + response.authResponse.accessToken);


                  var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                  var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;

                  testAPI();
                }
                else
                 {
                  console.log("not connected");
                 }
              },{scope: 'email,user_birthday,user_location,user_hometown'});



 function testAPI()
   {

      console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');


      FB.api('/me', {fields: 'name,email,birthday,hometown,location'}, (response) => {
              console.log('name: ' + response.name);
              console.log('email: ' + response.email);
              console.log('birth: ' + response.birthday);
              console.log('home: ' + response.hometown.name);
              console.log('location: ' + response.location.name);






         });

   }
```

Tried also `location.name` and `location`, non works.

There is something about including a `token` in some examples here, but nobody talks about it clearly in FB, or here, and its unclear to me if you need it or not and when .

Comment: Using string concatenation when logging objects is a rather bad idea. Please log your complete response object to console, and inspect that.

Comment: Works fine for me in Graph API Explorer, if the necessary permission is granted. I would suggest you test your requests in there first, so that you can exclude the possibility it is an issue specific to your code.